# How to avoid catastrophic backtracking with this specific pattern

Tags: regex, backtracking

I run into a catastrophic backtracking problem with this big reg pattern my predecessor wrote.
We basically just want to filter out salaries out of job descriptions.

This is the pattern:

```
(?:(?:(?:\bEURO|\bEuro|\beuro|\bEUR|\bEur|\beur|€)[[:punct:]]?\W*(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?))|(?:(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?)(?:\W*(?:\bEURO|\bEuro|\beuro|\bEUR|\bEur|\beur|€))))|(?:(?:(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\W|salary)\w*\W+(?:[a-zA-Z[:punct:]]+\W+){0,6}(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?))|(?:(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?)(?:\w*\W+){0,6}\w*(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\W|salary)))
```

It basically does what it is intended to do, but inside my Java application it causes a freeze on some Job strings. That must not happen.

I am almost certain that this can be done much easier and a hundred times better, I just don't have the time to learn regex on an advanced level. Maybe some pros have a quick, first glance idea how to prevent the catastrophic backtracking problem and help me out.

It should recognize the patterns like

```
Eur 40.000

<some random text>gehalt: 2000-3000
```

(both numeric values so I can further process for min/max determination)

```
2000 - 50.000 euro
```

etc.

Examples:

Input:

```
We offer a salary of 40.000 - 50.000.
```

Matches:

```
40.000 , 50.000
```

Input:

```
date: 12.10.2020 - We offer eur 3000 - 20.000.
```

Matches:

```
3000 , 20.000
```

Input:

```
Hello world ! Today is: 12.10.2020 - We offer a Gehalt of eur3000-20.000
```

Matches:

```
3000 , 20.000
```

The problem occurs with crazy strings like
[Crazy String that unfortunately can occur during a web crawl](https://regex101.com/r/BGXYdP/1/)

Comment: Points for the new coinage "cacktracking" but I'm feeling compelled to change it to the regular established term.

Comment: It's hard to guess what some repeating fragments like `(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?` are really supposed to capture. It's possible to guess what you hoped the regex would mean but it would be better still if you could spell this out.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. It seems that your first example doesn't actually match, though. See https://regex101.com/r/ZflJFQ/1

Comment: Indeed it doesnt, but this is a secondary concern for now. My main concern it that the program does not freeze because of the catastrophic backtracking. I will post an example String: https://regex101.com/r/BGXYdP/1 Strings like this should never happen... but they CAN happen unfortunately...

Comment: I don't see a lot of opportunity for backtracking here, though e.g. `(?:\bEURO|\bEuro|\beuro|\bEUR|\bEur|\beur|€)[[:punct:]]?\W*(?:(?<!\d)` is hugely redundant. `[[:punct:]]` overlaps with `\W` and so the regex engine has to try matching every punctuation character as `\W` if the match fails when it consumes the punctuation, which introduces some, but certainly not - in isolation - catastrophic, backtracking. `(?:\b(?:EURO?|[Ee]uro?)|€)\W*` matches the same strings much more succinctly, without backtracking (`(?<!\d)` is redundant because the match could not be a number anyway).

Comment: ... But I guess the higher-order regex with A|B|C is hugely prone to backtracking if there is overlap between A and B and C. Could you refactor to avoid matching nearly the same strings in multiple ways? Can you spell out what A and B and C (or however many alterations you have) should match in isolation?

Comment: First of all thanks very much for your time.Im not sure what you mean by A|B|C. I can do whatever i want with the pattern basicly. The match is not so important at this moment as to avoid the program freeze,.. did you try the link i have posted ? Dont you get the catastrophic backtracking error ?

Comment: It seems like this part is causing the backtracking problem ------->      `(?:(?:(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\W|salary)\w*\W+(?:[a-zA-Z[:punct:]]+\W+){0,6}(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?))|(?:(?:(?<!\d)(?:(\d{1,3}(?:[,.\'\s])\d{3})|([12]?\d{3,5}))(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|-|--))?)(?:\w*\W+){0,6}\w*(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\W|salary)))`

Comment: See this https://regex101.com/r/BGXYdP/3

Comment: Yes, I see the catastrophic backtracking error. I tried to make sense of your regex but I had to guess too many things and it's rather humongous. Again, my guess as to why it backtracks is that you have three (if I read this correctly) nearly identical patterns and so the regex engine basically has to try backing out of the branch a lot of times when matching fails.

Comment: Yeah im not a good question poster either. i am aware of that. Well im trying to create a temporary solution now at least. I only want to match certain  numbers. This is what i have come up with for now https://regex101.com/r/zilASa/1 I dont know why (at the end of the pattern ) `(?!=[\d]+)` the first numbers of a phonenumber still match when there is this negative lookahead that should prevent it if a 4 or 5 digit number is succeeded by any amount of numbers. Any idea ? I dont want the 12242 to match.

Comment: Uh, because you probably meant `(?!\d)`(notice also how `[\d]` is just a redundant alias for `\d`). Updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/zilASa/3

Comment: But notice also that I could not have guessed what you actually meant if you had not also explained it in prose. Something similar would be necessary for the main question.

Comment: Did any suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `[:punct:]` expression matches punctuation that can be also matches by `\W`, so `\W+(?:[a-zA-Z[:punct:]]+\W+){0,6}` must be replaced with `\W+(?:[a-zA-Z]+\W+){0,6}`.
The `(?:\w*\W+){0,6}` is also catastrophic backtracking prone, since `\w*` matches 0 or more word characters and as such the pattern is of the `(A+)+` type.
Replace with `\w*(?:\W+\w+){0,6}\W+`.

`--|-` must be shrunk to `--?` to use as few alternatives with the same first characters as possible.

A ton of redundant non-capturing groups, some redundant lookbehinds are removed.

The rest of changes are just enhancing

Use

```js
(?:(?:\bEURO?|€)\W*(\d{1,3}[,.\'\s]\d{3}|[12]?\d{3,5})(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|--?))?|(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}[,.\'\s]\d{3}|[12]?\d{3,5})(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|--?))?\W*(?:\bEURO?|€))|(?:(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\b|salary)\w*\W+(?:[a-zA-Z]+\W+){0,6}(\d{1,3}[,.\'\s]\d{3}|[12]?\d{3,5})(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|--?))?|(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}[,.\'\s]\d{3}|[12]?\d{3,5})(?!\d)(?:[,.](?:\d\d|--?))?\w*(?:\W+\w+){0,6}\W+(?:gehalt|lohn|entgelt|netto|brutto|überzahlung|kollektivvertrag|wage\b|salary))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/QpEHQp/2)